# Mostrar y ocultar formulario al crear elementos dinámicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estoy tratando de crear formularios de manera dinámica que contienen un botón de settings que a la hora de hacer click me despliegue otro formulario oculto, el problema es que a la hora de agregar nuevos formularios, no me despliega los formularios ocultos, Agradezco su ayuda!

```js
 var count = 1;
        $("#add").click(function() {
            var html = "<div id='formulario" + count + "'><br> <div class='col-md-12'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Cantidad' id='cantidad'><div class='col-md-3 icon-tk'><a href='javascript: void(0)' id='settings'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon settings' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a> <a href='javascript: void(0)' id='settings-second' style='display:none;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon settings' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a><a href='javascript: void(0)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon remove-ticket' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a></div><div class='ticket-settings' style='display:none; margin-top:15px;' id='tk-settings'><div class='form-group'><label style='margin-top:10px;'>Descripción</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: Incluye bebida - Únicamente para adultos -  Prohibido el ingreo de alimentos '></div><div class='form-group'><p>Por compra: <input type='text' class='form-control to-buy' placeholder='0 tiquetes'></p></div><div class='form-group'><label style='margin-top:10px;'>Mensaje:</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Entradas Agotadas'></div></div></div></div>";

            var form = $(html);

            $("#element").append(form);
            
        /* Mostrar tickets settings*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#settings").click(function() {
                $("#settings").hide();
                $("#settings-second").show();
                $("#tk-settings").show('slow');
            });
        });
        /* Ocultar tickets settings*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#settings-second").click(function() {
                $("#settings-second").hide();
                $("#settings").show();
                $("#tk-settings").hide('slow');
            });
        });
            
            count++;
        });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Agregar</button>
    <div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle es bastaste simple, al añadir los `listeners` a los elementos `#settings-second` y `#settings` estos aún no existen en el `DOM`, por lo cuál los eventos no funcionarán.

Si se está inyectando `HTML` nuevo en el `DOM` *(dinámicamente)* , es preferible usar [eventos delegados](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) para adjuntar un controlador de eventos, usando un elemento existente en el `DOM`, para este caso sería al elemento `document`

Otra aclaración importante  es que no es necesario tener `$(document).ready` más de 1 vez, bastaría con 1. Y los listeners para `#settings` y  `#settings-second` fuera del listener para el evento `click` del botón. Claro que esto afectaría en la forma que accedería a los elementos para mostrar u ocultar. *(explicación en el código)*

```js
$(function() {
   var count = 1;
    $("#add").click(function() {
            var html = "<div id='formulario" + count + "'><br> <div class='col-md-12'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Cantidad' id='cantidad'><div class='col-md-3 icon-tk'><a href='javascript: void(0)' id='settings'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon settings' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a> <a href='javascript: void(0)' id='settings-second' style='display:none;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon settings' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a><a href='javascript: void(0)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon remove-ticket' style='margin:5px; color: black;'></span></a></div><div class='ticket-settings' style='display:none; margin-top:15px;' id='tk-settings'><div class='form-group'><label style='margin-top:10px;'>Descripción</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Ej: Incluye bebida - Únicamente para adultos -  Prohibido el ingreo de alimentos '></div><div class='form-group'><p>Por compra: <input type='text' class='form-control to-buy' placeholder='0 tiquetes'></p></div><div class='form-group'><label style='margin-top:10px;'>Mensaje:</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Entradas Agotadas'></div></div></div></div>";
            var form = $(html);
            $("#element").append(form);
        count++;
    });
    $(document).on("click","#settings" , function() {
        // this hace referencia al element donde se realizo el evento
        $(this).hide(); //ocultamos element settings
        // accedemos al elemento  hermano
        // con id settings-second
        $(this).siblings("#settings-second").show();
         // accedemos al elemento padre y luego al hermano
        // con id tk-settings y lo mostramos
        $(this).parent().siblings("#tk-settings").show('slow');
    });
     $(document).on("click","#settings-second" , function() {
        $(this).hide();//ocultamos element settings-second
        //buscamos el elemento hermano con id settings y lo mostramos
        $(this).siblings("#settings").show();
        // accedemos al elemento padre y luego al hermano
        // con id tk-settings y lo ocultamos
        $(this).parent().siblings("#tk-settings").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Agregar</button>
<div id="element"></div>
```